# Adding indexes in mogodb

Tags: mongodb

I currently have a mongodb database which is pretty unstructured. I am attempting to extract all the followers of a given set of profiles on twitter. My database looks like this:

```
{'123':1
 '123':2
 '123':3
 '567':8
 '567':9
}
```

Where each key is a user and the value is a single follower. When I attempt to create an index on these keys, I simply run out of the available index as I have a lot of users (8 million). After googling, I find that the maximum number of indexes I can have is about 64. How do I create a proper indexing on this database? OR would you suggest a different way for me to store my data?

Comment: You can have 64 different index _definitions_ per collection; there's no limit I know of on the number of documents those indexes can support.

Comment: All my 8 million entries are in one collection. In my above example, I will need 2 indexes. One to index the key 123 and the other for 567. I have nearly 3000 such unique keys.

Comment: OK, sounds like it isn't feasible to index your current schema and you're going to need to consider modifying your schema so that your `'123'`, `'567'`, etc. keys become values of a common key instead.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to make my keys a part of an external key.

Answer (score 0):

You should structure your data differently.

I would recommend you to have a collection of "user" documents, where every user has an array "followers". This array should be filled with unique identifiers of the users who follow (like name, _id or your own ID number).

```
{ name: "userA",
  followers: [
     "userB",
     "userC"
  ] 
},
{ name: "userB",
  followers: [
     "userD",
     "userF"
 ] 
},
```

You can then create an index on the followers field to quickly find all users who follow an other user. When you want to find all users who follow the users "userX", "userY" and "userZ", you would then do it with this query:

```
db.users.find({followers: { $all: ["userX", "userY", "userZ" ] } });
```

**Edit:**

To add a follower to a user, use the $push operator:

```
db.users.update({name:"userA"}, { $push: { followers: "userB" } } );
```

The $pull operator can be used to remove array enries:

```
db.users.update({name:"userA"}, { $pull: { followers: "userB" } } );
```

Comment: A single list in this case can include more than 1 million followers. How can I insert and update into this field easily? Also, can't I just create a database which looks like: {followers:{'123' : 456, '123' : 567, ....}}?

Comment: This won't work, because the field '123' can't have both the values 456 and 567. I added a paragraph to the end of my answer which explains how to add and remove single entries from arrays.